# Ошибка: Warning: Illegal string offset как разобрать?

Tags: php

Есть Массив:

```
$_admin_left_menu =
    Array(
        array(
            "section_name" => "Контент1",
            array(
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            )
        ),
        array(
            "section_name" => "Контент2",
            array(
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news3/",
                "icon" => "default"
            )
        )
    );
```

Далее я вывожу через `foreach` только `"section_name"` следующим кодом:

```
foreach ($_admin_left_menu as $section_value) {
    echo $section_value['section_name'] . "<br>";
}
```

На выходе я получаю (Контент1 и Контент2).

Далее вывожу с этого же массва например `"link"` следующим кодом:

```
foreach ($_admin_left_menu as $section_value) {
    echo $section_value['section_name'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($section_value as $value) {
        echo $value['link'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Данные выводит, но в добавок получаю это  `Illegal string offset 'name' in` и `�`.

Такую стуктуру массива использую для меню, так будет легче с ним работать, и данные я вводу вручную. 
Почитав понял что нужно обращться к таким строчкам через номер массива... `$value[0]` и данного предупреждения нет! Но `�` остался.

Конечноже не удобно использовать номер массива а испрользовать индекс массива напрмиер так `['section_name']`.

Хотелось бы узнать более подробней как могу придти к требуемому результату? Ведь удобней так `echo $value['section_name'];` писать чем `echo $value[0];`

```
PHP Version 7.3.15
```

Comment: Какая версия php? Если больше 5.4, то можно спокойно делать section_name[]

Comment: @Apelsin2020, не совсем Вас понял

Comment: Скажите, какая у Вас версия php

Comment: @Apelsin2020    7.3.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема не в версии php, а неверной структуре данных.

```
$_admin_left_menu = [
    [
        "section_name" => "Контент1",
        "links" => [
            [
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            ],
        ]
    ], 
    [
        "section_name" => "Контент2",
        "links" => [
            [
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news3/",
                "icon" => "default"
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

Соответственно цикл получаем таким:

```
foreach ($_admin_left_menu as $section_value) {
    echo $section_value['section_name'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($section_value['links'] as $value) {
        echo $value['link'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Да и такой подход с мега-массивом не совсем уместен. Правильнее было бы обернуть всё это в классы. Как минимум в `Section` и `Link`.

**UPD**

```
class Section {

    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    /** @var Link[] */
    private $links;

    public __construct($name, array $links) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->links = $links;
    } 
}

class Link {
    private $name;
    private $url;
    private $icon;

    public __construct($name, $url, $icon) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->url= $url;
        $this->icon = $icon;
    } 
}
```

Как пользоваться, думаю, разберётесь. Геттеры и сеттеры нужные добавите под себя

Comment: `Правильнее было бы обернуть всё это в классы. Как минимум в Section и Link.` Не совсем понял обвернуть это всё в классы. А вот при строении массива использовали квадратные скобки - что это ?)

Comment: @МаксимСиваконь, обновил ответ. `[]` - альтернативная запись `array()`

Answer (score 1):

Тут уже дали великолепный ответ, как лучше сделать, чтобы всё правильно работало. Дополню это объяснением, почему не работал Ваш первоначальный вариант. Думаю, это будет полезно. Вот Ваш код:

```
foreach ($_admin_left_menu as $section_value) {
    echo $section_value['section_name'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($section_value as $value) {
        echo $value['link'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Строка `echo $section_value['section_name'] . "<br>";` сработает правильно, поскольку массив `$_admin_left_menu` состоит из 2 массивов (`$_admin_left_menu[0]` и `$_admin_left_menu[1]`) и каждый из этих массивов содержит элемент с индексом `'section_name'`.

Но вот в Вашем внутреннем `foreach` начинают твориться тёмные дела. `Foreach` проходит по массиву `$section_value` и в каждом его элементе ищет вложенный элемент c индексом `'link'`. Посмотрим на массив `$_admin_left_menu[0]` (далее будем обращаться к нему как к `$section_value`):

```
array(
            "section_name" => "Контент1",
            array(
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Контент",
                "link" => "/news/",
                "icon" => "default"
            )
        )
```

Он состоит из 3 элементов. Первый имеет индекс `"section_name"`. Второму и третьему элементам Вы не задали индексы в явном виде. Поэтому PHP присвоил им числовые индексы. (Если ключ для элемента массива не указан явно, PHP использует в качестве ключа предыдущее наибольшее значение ключа типа integer, увеличенное на 1. Если Вы явно задавали элементам строковые индексы, а потом добавили в массив элемент без явно указанного индекса, PHP присвоит ему индекс 0). Элементы `$section_value[0]` и `$section_value[1]` сами являются массивами, и каждый из них содержит элемент с индексом `'link'`. Для них Ваш код отработает правильно. А вот элемент `$section_value['section_name']` - не является массивом. Это строка `"Контент1"`. Но Ваш внутренний `foreach` всё равно попытается извлечь из него элемент с индексом `'link'`. Это приведёт к ошибке, поскольку индексом в строке может быть только число.

Обращение `$value[0]` действительно уберёт ошибку, но Вы получите совсем не то, что хотели. Элемент с индексом 0 у Вас есть только в строках `"Контент1"` и `"Контент2"`. Оттуда его и выведет в виде кракозябра (посимвольно русские буквы нормально не выводятся). Если Вы замените `"Контент1"` и `"Контент2"` на `"Content1"` и `"Content2"` соответственно, то Вы увидите, что вместо кракозябра будет напечатана буква `'C'`.